# Is this polynomial irreducible over rationals?

Tags: linear-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

$f(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots+\frac{x^n}{n!}$.

I know that if n is prime, time $n!$ on both sides, since $n$ is prime, Eisenstein criterion shows $f(x)$ is irreducible. Is it also true for arbitrary finite positive integer $n$?

Comment: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/schurtheorem.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes...but I have not seen a short proof.

[here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/schurtheorem.pdf) is a (not short) proof.